# how can I update wso2 api manager to this version wso2am-3.2.0.117?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The latest update level is 'wso2am-3.2.0.117'.
This consists of 473 updates
applied on top of 'wso2am-3.2.0.0'[WARNING]
The update level
'wso2am-3.2.0.117' consists of 54 critical security updates applied on top of
'wso2am-3.2.0.0'.
WSO2 strongly recommends to use 'wso2am-3.2.0.117'
distribution in production as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a WSO2 subscription to update the pack. Instructions can be found in https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/update-tool/

Comment: when I run this command it gives me error 500

Comment: You need provide subscription credentials when running the command. Without a valid subscription, it will not proceed.